# Saving a child when deleting a parent node

Tags: javascript, dom

I try make a toolbar which is appended to a table row after clicking on it. In the code below the functionality of the toolbar is limited just to deletion a row to make things clearer. The idea is to "park" the toolbar into tools DIV (which is hidden in the real app) when it is not used and when its row is going to be deleted. The problem is that the toolbar disappears after deletion of the table row. This is strange because first it is successfully appended to its "home" (the tools DIV) and it is removed from the row which has to be deleted. So the toolbar should be safe. However when onclick event ends the toolbar is gone. Watch the snippet below to see the situation before alert box and after it. What is going on?

```js
function addToolbar(cell) {
  cell.appendChild(document.getElementById('toolbar'));
}

function deleteRow(rownum) {
  document.getElementById('tools').appendChild(document.getElementById('toolbar'));
  document.getElementById('mytable').deleteRow(rownum);
  alert('Now the toolbar is parked back to the "tools" DIV as it is suppossed to be. After you click OK the deleteRow() function returns and the toolbar will be deleted. Why?');
}
```

```css
#tools, #mytable, #toolbar {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div id='tools'>
  TOOLS DIV. Here is a place for parking the toolbar when not used.
  Unfortunatelly it disappears 
  <div id='toolbar' onclick='deleteRow(this.parentNode.rowIndex)'>
    Delete this row
  </div>
</div>
<br>
Click on the table rows below to append the "toolbar".
<table id='mytable'>
  <tr onclick='addToolbar(this);'>
    <td>
      First row
    </td>
    <td>
      <!--a place for the toolbar-->
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr onclick='addToolbar(this)'>
    <td>
      Second row
    </td>
    <td>
      <!--a place for the toolbar-->
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please try to create jsfiddle for your code.

Comment: Here is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mjeh4p3q/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening is that a click event targeting the toolbar bubbles up to the parent node (in this case, the `tr` row), triggering its `onclick` handler.

You may prevent this mechanism by passing the event object to your deleteRow function, and calling its `stopPropagation` method.

```js
function addToolbar(cell) {
  cell.appendChild(document.getElementById('toolbar'));
}

function deleteRow(event, rownum) {
  document.getElementById('tools').appendChild(document.getElementById('toolbar'));
  document.getElementById('mytable').deleteRow(rownum);
  alert('Now the toolbar is parked back to the "tools" DIV as it is suppossed to be. After you click OK the deleteRow() function returns and the toolbar will be deleted. Why?');

  event.stopPropagation();
}
```

```css
#tools, #mytable, #toolbar {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div id='tools'>
  TOOLS DIV. Here is a place for parking the toolbar when not used.
  Unfortunatelly it disappears 
  <div id='toolbar' onclick='deleteRow(event, this.parentNode.rowIndex)'>
    Delete this row
  </div>
</div>
<br>
Click on the table rows below to append the "toolbar".
<table id='mytable'>
  <tr onclick='addToolbar(this);'>
    <td>
      First row
    </td>
    <td>
      <!--a place for the toolbar-->
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr onclick='addToolbar(this)'>
    <td>
      Second row
    </td>
    <td>
      <!--a place for the toolbar-->
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I am not entirely sure the `event` object is available in the HTML declaration on all current browsers, so I would advise attaching event listeners programmatically.